# Desmos Graph Color with Command

Tags: desmos

Is there a command like y=x {color: black} to change the graph colors rather than going into the settings and changing every single graph manually.

Searches only seem to show to change colors through the settings button.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite what you're looking for, but it might help. I create a custom color and use it for all related graphs. Instead of changing each graph individually,I change the custom color to a new color, which changes all the graphs at once. There's probably a better way, but I'm fairly new to Desmos, so that's the best I can do.